# Special handling of quotes on Mac

Tags: macos, textinput

When I type ' or " on my Mac (OS X 10.7.4) it underlines it and depending on next symbol treats the combination as a special character (for example ä for " + a).

How can I turn that off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a foreign input source. You should go to System Preferences -> Language & Text -> input and make sure you are using the correct language.

However this is not a programming question, so this post will probably get removed.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem - I used U.S. International PC input source.